# How to call parent method and pass any child that extending the parent struct as argument in Golang

Tags: go, composition

I'm still learning Golang and I want to ask something.
Is it possible to do something like this and passing any other child to PMethod that extending Parent struct?

```
type Parent struct{
   PAttribute string
}

func (p *Parent) PMethod(c *Child){
   fmt.Println("this is parent Attribute : " + p.PAttribute)
   fmt.Println("this is child Attribute : " + c.CAttribute)
}

type Child struct{
   Parent
   CAttribute string
}

type Child2 struct{
   Parent
   CAttribute string
}


func main(){
   c := Child{
         Parent{
            "parent"
         },
         "child",
        }
   c.PMethod(&c)

   c2 := Child2{
         Parent{
            "parent"
         },
         "child",
        }
   c2.PMethod(&c2)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This is all wrong and probably an XY problem. Stop thinking about parent/child object hierarchies now and forever because there _is_ _no_ _such_ _thing_ _in_ _Go_ and there is no sensible way to simulate it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, so do you have any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no problem description jet. A question like "How do I eat spaghetti properly if I ordered a beer?" Is not answerable.

Comment: You'd have better luck if you give a concrete problem you face with real code, rather than an abstract example. If just starting out, be sure to read effective go (linked below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, forget about inheritance, [Go doesn't have inheritance](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance) for good reasons. So stop thinking in terms of parents and children. Go has [composition](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) (which you're using here), but it behaves differently. You could use [interfaces](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces) in Go in order to pass in Child and Child2 and have the receiver indifferent as to which one it gets (as long as it has the same functions). BUT this is probably a mistake as you're trying to recreate the inheritance you are familiar with in Go. Don't do that.

If your types are related like this, you should probably take a step back from an embedded class accepting instances of a class to modify. The embedded class should act upon its own fields, and that's it - this compartmentalizes concerns and keeps data with the methods that act on it. So instead of thinking about Parents and Children, think about a bit of code/data you want to share.

Consider the classic inheritance problem Animals - with cats and dogs. With inheritance you'd have a Cat and a Dog and an abstract base class Animal. Animal might have all the methods you expect then you write perhaps a Say() method on Animal which says nothing and Say() which woofs and Say() which Meows on Dogs and Cats.

In Go you'd simply have Cats and Dogs and a different Say() method on each which both conform to a Speaker() interface someone else defines. Prefer a bit of duplication to lots of extra code and complexity just to share a little behaviour.

Be sure to read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and try to use the tools available, rather than recreating tools like inheritance you're familiar with.

Comment: That's why codes in GO are often repetitive. You guys just don't admit that in the real world many things are quite similar to each other. So why do I have to define them all in details and tell them how to work in details.